# Is is possible to make C# Chat Server using sockets with Android client

Tags: c#, android

newbie here. I successfully created a chat server using c# (server partial code below, got it somewhere though. rights goes to the owner) and clients able to connect and it is working as expected. now my question is can I make a client application that will connect from android?

```
    private void loadchatserver()
    {
        try
        {
            // Initialise the ArrayList of connected clients
            this.clientList = new ArrayList();

            // Initialise the delegate which updates the status
            this.updateStatusDelegate = new UpdateStatusDelegate(this.UpdateStatus);

            // Initialise the socket
            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            // Initialise the IPEndPoint for the server and listen on port 30000
            IPEndPoint server = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, pubcommandport);

            // Associate the socket with this IP address and port
            serverSocket.Bind(server);

            // Initialise the IPEndPoint for the clients
            IPEndPoint clients = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            // Initialise the EndPoint for the clients
            EndPoint epSender = (EndPoint)clients;

            // Start listening for incoming data
            serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(this.serverdataStream, 0, this.serverdataStream.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epSender, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveServerData), epSender);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
              MessageBox.Show("Loadchatserver: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can.
Sockets are a global protocol that any major programming language supports.

Here's a nice tutorial for Sockets in Java (should work the same way with Dalvik - the Android implementation of Java):
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: Thanks Svarog. that was fast and the link is very helpful.